# Fetching crossed records from database

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure (simplified):

```
id | structure_id | structure_hash_id
1    1              1
2    1              2
3    1              3
4    2              4
5    2              1
6    3              2
```

As you can see, all structures contain many structure hashes. What I want to fetch is information for each structure id, how many structure hashes it contains exist in other structures. So for this example it'd be:

```
structure_id #1: 2
structure_id #2: 1
structure_id #3: 1
```

The query I wrote for this is:

```
SELECT contains.structure_id, COUNT(contains.structure_hash_id)
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM structureTable st
   WHERE structure_id = 1
) AS contains
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT *
   FROM structureTable st
   WHERE structure_id != 1
) AS notcontains
ON contains.structure_hash_id = notcontains.structure_hash_id
GROUP BY contains.structure_id;
```

It works, I wrote it from memory, I don't remember how I wrote it earlier as I deleted it, but you got the idea.

But the problem is that in real table I've got ~500mln records and some other columns, so for each structure_id the query execution time is huge (> 15min).

Also, I have type structure_id manually, while I'd like to have them all as a result like I gave an example at the top of this post.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with self join and group by.

Here is the way to do that:

```
select  
t1.structure_id ,
count(t1.structure_id ) as count

from  structure  t1 
inner join structure  t2 on t1.structure_id !=t2.structure_id  
and t1.structure_hash_id=t2.structure_hash_id
group by t1.structure_id
```

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/678bf7/1/0